# An Inequality involving minimum

Tags: inequality

For any two functions $f_1(\cdot)$ and $f_2(\cdot)$ and for any $A$ and $B$, is this always true that 
$$\min_B f_1(B) + \min_A f_2(A) \geq \min_A f_1(A) + \min_B f_2(B)$$

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$? Sets?

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey: Subset in the domain of these functions.

Comment: @applied_math If $A$ is a subset of the domain of $f,$ then what does $f(A)$ mean. Usually, it means the image of $A,$ but it seems you're using it differently here.

Comment: Consider A to be the point where $f_1$ is maximum and B to be the point where $f_2$ is maximum...

Answer (score 0):

This definitely is not always true. Consider $f_1$ and $f_2$ such that the equality is $>$, not $\geq$. Then consider switching their roles; the inequality will be flipped.

A similar argument could be applied to $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0):

For an explicit counterexample take $f_1(x)=x,f_2(x)=-x,A=\{0,1\}$ and $B=\{1,2\}$.